# Why do we need 2F prepare certificates instead of just F+1 in PBFT?

Tags: blockchain, consensus, algorithms, hyperledger

I started reading PBFT and I could not understand: why do we need 2F prepare certificates?

The client needs only F + 1 replies, not 2F, so why can't the same rule be applicable in the prepare phase of the protocol?

Same question in the commit phase, but this time it is even weirder: we need at least 2F + 1, again why not only F + 1, I just know that the quorum intersection must be more than 2F + 1 but we only need F + 1 replies from that quorum intersection as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

For a detailed answer, please read [Lamport *et al.* paper](https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/byz.pdf).

For a short answer, I'll explain it downwards. To coming readers, please note that we are discussing the [PBFT paper](https://pmg.csail.mit.edu/papers/osdi99.pdf).

Assume that we have only three processes (named *p0*, *p1* and *p2*) and a client *c*, where *p2* is a faulty process. That said, we have **2F+1** processes.

In the Prepare phase, *p1* receives two votes one from *p0* (an honest vote) and one from *p2* (a faulty vote). Which decision should *p1* write into the database? You can simply notice that no-one (neither *p0* nor *p2*) is overweighing, which leads to an inconsistency. That's why we need **3F+1** (and accordingly, each process requires **2F+1** replies) processes to achieve consistency.

Roughly speaking: **XF+1** replicas means **XF** replies.